# Delete [tag:trash]

Tags: discussion, tags

All relevant questions about [trash](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trash) appear to really be about [pantheon-files](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pantheon-files) and its operation. The Trash tag is better either as a synonym or just deleted altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has also been merged and linked.